# Query Regarding JSON jar

Tags: java, json

i'm little confuse while selecting json jar ,sometimes i'm using json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar or sometimes json-lib-0.9.jar which one is appropriate..?
Some methods are also change in both of them like json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar  uses add() method foa adding in json array and json-lib-0.9.jar uses put for the same work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, version "2.2.2" is a stable release that targets Java 5 and above.  In contrast, version "0.9" sounds like it was a pre-release developer build. I would select "2.2.2" on that basis.

**Unless** of course this is a false dichotomy, and they're actually two completely separate projects; in which case I would evaluate their features and fitness individually.

To digress from your question; I personally would select a recent release of [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) or [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: Even though i solved my issues by using the jars:
commons-beanutils-1.7.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ezmorph.jar
json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar
: http://www.java4s.com/json/jars-required-to-work-with-json-in-java-applications/
but here the size is 1.2 mb

Comment: @Pankajkumarsharma And it runs on your Server (which uses a fair bit more then 1.2 MB). You might want to lean [maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html).